# Can ASDoc generate documents for an AIR and Flash project at the same time?

Tags: flash, actionscript, asdoc

I'm trying to use ASDoc to generate code for two projects, one runs in AIR, the other in Flash.  I can create an ASDoc config file that works for each one individually, but when I combine them, I get errors about contextMenu and File, because AIR and Flash have separate APIs for them.

My config:

```
<flex-config>
    <doc-classes>
        <class>FlashProject</class>
        <class>AIRProject</class>
    </doc-classes>
    <compiler>
        <external-library-path>
            <path-element>${flexlib}\libs\player\10.0\playerglobal.swc</path-element>
            <path-element>${flexlib}\libs\air\airglobal.swc</path-element>
        </external-library-path>
        <library-path>
            <path-element>${flexlib}\libs</path-element>
            <path-element>${flexlib}\libs\air</path-element>
            <path-element>${flexlib}\locale\{locale}</path-element>
        </library-path>
        <source-path>
            <path-element>FlashProject\src</path-element>
            <path-element>AIRProject\src</path-element>
        </source-path>
    </compiler>
</flex-config>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use an ANT build script and configure both projects as seperate tasks.

Comment: I will provide a sample build script tomorrow.

Comment: I didn't word the question very well, but I want all the documentation together.  If I just run ASDoc twice, I get two index files, etc.  There is a lot of shared code, and I want to have it all in one place.

Comment: Guess it doesn't make sense to give ANT a try, because the config would basically look the same as yours.